# My Git submodules are not loading all files

Tags: git, submodule

I have about 8 submodules in my project (/modules/..) and some of them are not fully checking out. In other words, when I run

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

Some of the submodule directories do not contain the all the files. My first thought was that I might be on a diffenet commit or something. But when I check the latest project commit - and then check the current commit of the submodule they are the same.

```
git submodule status
```

How do I get git to pull ALL the submodule files when it loads the submodules? Or rather, how is it possible that I'm only receiving some of the files when I create the submodule folder?

My project structure looks like this:

```
/project
/modules
  /submodule1
  /submodule2
  /etc...
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I still don't know what the deal is. But I deleted the submodule folders and ran

```
git submodule update
```

to re-checkout a copy of the submodules and fix the missing files.

Comment: Does not work for me. Some submodules are missing. `.git/config` does not contain these modules and they are not in `.git/modules`

Answer (score 0):

If the submodule is not being pulled make sure you have added.

For example:

`git submodule add https://github.com/chaconinc/DbConnector`

I had the same issue and after running the above command it worked.